# XSLT sum grouped table cell

Tags: xslt

Maybe you can help me.
I don't know how to sum some table's cell "Year" which are grouped by "Title". I need that sum cell also would be merge as first cell "Title".

I used sum(), but it returs 0.

XMl Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2001</YEAR>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylan1</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2002</YEAR>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylanas</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2003</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylan</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2004</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylanas</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque1</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2005</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylan</artist1>
</Row>
<Row>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque1</TITLE>
    <YEAR>2006</YEAR>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <artist1>Bob Dylanas</artist1>
</Row>
</LIST>
```

XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="cds" match="Row" use="TITLE" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Artist1</th>
    </tr> 
<xsl:for-each select="LIST/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('cds', TITLE)[1])]" >   
    <tr>
  <td>
      <xsl:if test="key('cds', TITLE)[1]">
          <xsl:attribute name="rowspan">
              <xsl:value-of select="count(key('cds', TITLE))" />
          </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
  </td>     
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/>
  </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </td>
  <td>      
      <xsl:value-of select="artist1"/>
  </td>
</tr>    
<xsl:for-each select="key('cds', TITLE)[position() > 1]">
<tr>
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="YEAR"/>
  </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="artist1"/>
    </td>
</tr>    
</xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now result is that:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `sum()` you have tried, even if it did only return 0. Can you also show the output you expect in this case (ideally as code, not an image)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `sum(key('cds', TITLE)/YEAR)` inside of the for-each.